# Android Studio!! Buttons for different screen sizes

Tags: android, button, screen

What should I change so that my button can auto-adjust on any screen size?
XML layout is like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/white_background"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MyActivity">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Contact us: 2310251888 or at info@dei.edu.gr"
    android:id="@+id/textContact"
    android:textColor="#ff1e296b"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:gravity="center" />c

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Guest Login"
    android:id="@+id/guestlogin"
    android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:radius="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/userlogin"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#ff1e296b"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="or"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#eeeeee" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sign In"
    android:id="@+id/buttonSignIN"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/guestlogin"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/guestlogin"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/guestlogin"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/guestlogin"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#ff1e296b"
    android:onClick="signIn" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="or"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#eeeeee" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sign Up"
    android:id="@+id/buttonSignUP"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/guestlogin"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/guestlogin"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/guestlogin"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/guestlogin"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#ff1e296b" />
```

In nexus 4 for emulator everything appears fine but when I run the application in a phone with a smaller screen size the buttons cover a part of the image background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What should I change so that my button can auto-adjust on any screen
>   size?

You don't need to change anything since `dp` is a screen-independing value. See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

However, the following

```
android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/userlogin"
```

is unnecessary since you center the `View`.

Comment: Yes but I have a specific image background in my application!! Whenever i use an emulator of nexus 4 everything is being displayed fine!! However when I use an emulator of nexus S the buttons cover a part of the background because the screen size is smaller

Comment: @michalis please provide some screenshots as well as your complete layout XML

Comment: I don't have 10 reputation to provide screenshots~~ I have edited the posts and provided the full xml layout

Comment: if you use image background you need to create specific resolutions. 
you can read more a bout it here : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
It means that for one picture you have 4 versions of various sizes.

Comment: @michalis relative attributes like `android:layout_below` won't work in a `LinearLayout`, you have to use a `RelativeLayout` instead.